# Using GoogleDocs to display pdf with jQuery in iFrame cannot find the file

Tags: jquery, google-docs

I have been succesful using GoogleDocs to display PDFs on an iPad when being served from my Mac's personal web sharing server where I do all my development work.

However, when I run from our 64bit production Windows Server 2008 where the files are in a virtual direcotry, GooglDocs puts up an I'm Sorry message that it cannot find the file. Clicking on their "click here to download the file" link loads the file no problem in the iFrame but not in the GoogleDocs viewer.

Here is what my code looks like on my mac with no virtual directory...

```
iFrameSrc = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2F71.98.201.139%2FSectorPlansPDF%2FFM-01Q-16QMC1824(1).pdf";
iFrameSrc = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + iFrameSrc + "&embedded=true";
$('.viewer .ifrm').attr('src', iFrameSrc);
```

Unencoded the source looks like this...

```
iFrameSrc = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://71.98.201.139/SectorPlansPDF/FM-01Q-16QMC1824(1).pdf";
```

On the windows server with the virtual directory it looks like this...

```
iFrameSrc = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2FMyProdcutionSite.com%2FMyVirtualDir%2FSectorPlansPDF%2FFM-01Q-16QMC1824(1).pdf";
iFrameSrc = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + iFrameSrc + "&embedded=true";
$('.viewer .ifrm').attr('src', iFrameSrc);
```

Unencoded this one looks like this...

```
iFrameSrc = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://MyProdcutionSite.com/MyVirtualDir/SectorPlansPDF/FM-01Q-16QMC1824(1).pdf";
```

Anyone know why this is happening and if so how to get it to work? We turned off the firewall to make sure that was not causing the problem. I suspect that there is a setting in IIS that we do not have set properly.

Why don't I just use it in the iFrame without GoogleDocs, you ask? The PDF is much larger than the iFrame on the iPad and so, unacceptably, only the upper left corner of the PDF is visible when it loads. I cannot find a way to zoom the pdf to fit the iframe. GooglDocs automatically presents the pdf zoomed to fit in the viewer.

Thanks for any help.

John

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google Document Viewer, which lets you use their viewer with files not hosted on Google. Something like:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/example.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

More info: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html